# Command to update anaconda downgrade anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I am relatively new to python and in Stackoverflow and have the 2019.10 version of anaconda and saw that it launched 2020.02.

I would manually uninstall my current version and install the latest version, but I don't want to lose the packages I already have.

Then I saw that it has the command "conda update anaconda" but it appears that he wants to downgrade anaconda.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda update anaconda
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: done

## Package Plan ##

  environment location: D:\Anaconda3

  added / updated specs:
    - anaconda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    _anaconda_depends-2019.03  |           py37_0           6 KB
    anaconda-custom            |           py37_1           3 KB
    anaconda-project-0.8.4     |             py_0         215 KB
    asn1crypto-1.3.0           |           py37_0         164 KB
    astroid-2.3.3              |           py37_0         283 KB
    astropy-4.0                |   py37he774522_0         5.8 MB
    attrs-19.3.0               |             py_0          39 KB
    babel-2.8.0                |             py_0         5.3 MB
    backports.functools_lru_cache-1.6.1|             py_0          11 KB
    beautifulsoup4-4.8.2       |           py37_0         163 KB
    bitarray-1.2.1             |   py37he774522_0          82 KB
    bokeh-2.0.0                |           py37_0         5.2 MB
    bottleneck-1.3.2           |   py37h2a96729_0         106 KB
    ca-certificates-2020.1.1   |                0         125 KB
    certifi-2019.11.28         |           py37_0         154 KB
    cffi-1.14.0                |   py37h7a1dbc1_0         223 KB
    cloudpickle-1.3.0          |             py_0          30 KB
    colorama-0.4.3             |             py_0          20 KB
    conda-4.8.2                |           py37_0         2.8 MB
    contextlib2-0.6.0.post1    |             py_0          16 KB
    cryptography-2.8           |   py37h7a1dbc1_0         509 KB
    curl-7.68.0                |       h2a8f88b_0         125 KB
    cython-0.29.15             |   py37ha925a31_0         1.8 MB
    cytoolz-0.10.1             |   py37he774522_0         304 KB
    dask-2.12.0                |             py_0          13 KB
    dask-core-2.12.0           |             py_0         568 KB
    decorator-4.4.2            |             py_0          14 KB
    distributed-2.12.0         |           py37_0         962 KB
    docutils-0.16              |           py37_0         667 KB
    ffmpeg-4.2                 |       ha925a31_0        17.9 MB
    fsspec-0.6.2               |             py_0          53 KB
    future-0.18.2              |           py37_0         656 KB
    h5py-2.10.0                |   py37h5e291fa_0         808 KB
    hypothesis-5.5.4           |             py_0         227 KB
    imageio-2.6.1              |           py37_0         3.2 MB
    imagesize-1.2.0            |             py_0          10 KB
    importlib_metadata-1.5.0   |           py37_0          49 KB
    intel-openmp-2020.0        |              166         1.5 MB
    ipykernel-5.1.4            |   py37h39e3cac_0         175 KB
    ipython-7.13.0             |   py37h5ca1d4c_0         996 KB
    jedi-0.16.0                |           py37_0         758 KB
    jinja2-2.11.1              |             py_0         104 KB
    joblib-0.14.1              |             py_0         201 KB
    jsonschema-3.2.0           |           py37_0         112 KB
    jupyter_client-5.3.4       |           py37_0         157 KB
    jupyter_console-6.1.0      |             py_0          24 KB
    jupyter_core-4.6.1         |           py37_0          85 KB
    jupyterlab-1.2.6           |     pyhf63ae98_0         2.8 MB
    keyring-21.1.0             |           py37_0          73 KB
    krb5-1.17.1                |       hc04afaa_0         709 KB
    lazy-object-proxy-1.4.3    |   py37he774522_0          30 KB
    libcurl-7.68.0             |       h2a8f88b_0         270 KB
    liblief-0.9.0              |       ha925a31_3         5.3 MB
    libpython-2.1              |           py37_0          47 KB
    libssh2-1.9.0              |       h7a1dbc1_1         215 KB
    libtiff-4.1.0              |       h56a325e_0         737 KB
    llvmlite-0.31.0            |   py37ha925a31_0        10.2 MB
    lxml-4.5.0                 |   py37h1350720_0         1.1 MB
    matplotlib-3.1.3           |           py37_0          22 KB
    matplotlib-base-3.1.3      |   py37h64f37c6_0         4.9 MB
    mkl-2020.0                 |              166        98.9 MB
    mkl_fft-1.0.15             |   py37h14836fe_0         118 KB
    mock-4.0.1                 |             py_0          32 KB
    more-itertools-8.2.0       |             py_0          41 KB
    nbconvert-5.6.1            |           py37_0         475 KB
    nbformat-5.0.4             |             py_0          89 KB
    networkx-2.4               |             py_0         1.2 MB
    notebook-6.0.3             |           py37_0         4.3 MB
    numba-0.48.0               |   py37h47e9c7a_0         3.0 MB
    numexpr-2.7.1              |   py37h25d0782_0         125 KB
    numpy-1.18.1               |   py37h93ca92e_0           6 KB
    numpy-base-1.18.1          |   py37hc3f5095_1         3.8 MB
    numpydoc-0.9.2             |             py_0          31 KB
    openpyxl-3.0.3             |             py_0         162 KB
    openssl-1.1.1d             |       he774522_4         4.8 MB
    packaging-20.3             |             py_0          36 KB
    pandas-1.0.1               |   py37h47e9c7a_0         7.4 MB
    parso-0.6.1                |             py_0          69 KB
    partd-1.1.0                |             py_0          20 KB
    path-13.1.0                |           py37_0          36 KB
    path.py-12.4.0             |                0           7 KB
    pillow-7.0.0               |   py37hcc1f983_0         646 KB
    pluggy-0.13.1              |           py37_0          34 KB
    prompt_toolkit-3.0.3       |             py_0         242 KB
    psutil-5.7.0               |   py37he774522_0         337 KB
    py-1.8.1                   |             py_0          71 KB
    py-lief-0.9.0              |   py37ha925a31_3         1.8 MB
    pycosat-0.6.3              |   py37he774522_0          75 KB
    pycurl-7.43.0.5            |   py37h7a1dbc1_0          64 KB
    pygments-2.5.2             |             py_0         672 KB
    pylint-2.4.4               |           py37_0         443 KB
    pyodbc-4.0.30              |   py37ha925a31_0          68 KB
    pyopenssl-19.1.0           |           py37_0          91 KB
    pyparsing-2.4.6            |             py_0          64 KB
    pyrsistent-0.15.7          |   py37he774522_0          96 KB
    pytables-3.6.1             |   py37h1da0976_0         2.2 MB
    pytest-5.3.5               |           py37_0         384 KB
    pytest-astropy-0.8.0       |             py_0           9 KB
    pytest-astropy-header-0.1.2|             py_0          12 KB
    pytest-doctestplus-0.5.0   |             py_0          21 KB
    python-dateutil-2.8.1      |             py_0         224 KB
    python-levenshtein-0.12.0  |py37he774522_1001          84 KB
    pywavelets-1.1.1           |   py37he774522_0         3.4 MB
    pywin32-227                |   py37he774522_1         5.5 MB
    pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0       |        py37_1000          41 KB
    pywinpty-0.5.7             |           py37_0          50 KB
    pyyaml-5.3                 |   py37he774522_0         153 KB
    pyzmq-18.1.1               |   py37ha925a31_0         400 KB
    qtawesome-0.6.1            |             py_0         693 KB
    qtconsole-4.7.1            |             py_0          94 KB
    requests-2.23.0            |           py37_0          93 KB
    rope-0.16.0                |             py_0         126 KB
    ruamel_yaml-0.15.87        |   py37he774522_0         269 KB
    scikit-image-0.16.2        |   py37h47e9c7a_0        22.6 MB
    scikit-learn-0.22.1        |   py37h6288b17_0         4.7 MB
    scipy-1.4.1                |   py37h9439919_0        11.9 MB
    seaborn-0.10.0             |             py_0         163 KB
    setuptools-46.0.0          |           py37_0         535 KB
    six-1.14.0                 |           py37_0          27 KB
    soupsieve-1.9.5            |           py37_0          62 KB
    sphinx-2.4.0               |             py_0         1.1 MB
    sphinxcontrib-websupport-1.2.0|             py_0          35 KB
    sqlalchemy-1.3.13          |   py37he774522_0         1.4 MB
    sqlite-3.31.1              |       he774522_0         637 KB
    statsmodels-0.11.0         |   py37he774522_0         7.5 MB
    sympy-1.5.1                |           py37_0         8.4 MB
    tbb-2020.0                 |       h74a9793_0         161 KB
    tblib-1.6.0                |             py_0          16 KB
    terminado-0.8.3            |           py37_0          26 KB
    testpath-0.4.4             |             py_0          88 KB
    tornado-6.0.4              |   py37he774522_1         604 KB
    tqdm-4.42.1                |             py_0          56 KB
    typing_extensions-3.7.4.1  |           py37_0          44 KB
    urllib3-1.25.8             |           py37_0         170 KB
    vs2015_runtime-14.16.27012 |       hf0eaf9b_1         1.1 MB
    wcwidth-0.1.8              |             py_0          21 KB
    werkzeug-1.0.0             |             py_0         240 KB
    wheel-0.34.2               |           py37_0          66 KB
    xlsxwriter-1.2.7           |             py_0         111 KB
    xlwings-0.17.1             |           py37_0         739 KB
    zipp-2.2.0                 |             py_0          12 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:       284.2 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  _anaconda_depends  pkgs/main/win-64::_anaconda_depends-2019.03-py37_0
  hypothesis         pkgs/main/noarch::hypothesis-5.5.4-py_0
  matplotlib-base    pkgs/main/win-64::matplotlib-base-3.1.3-py37h64f37c6_0
  path               pkgs/main/win-64::path-13.1.0-py37_0
  pytest-astropy-he~ pkgs/main/noarch::pytest-astropy-header-0.1.2-py_0
  pywin32-ctypes     pkgs/main/win-64::pywin32-ctypes-0.2.0-py37_1000
  typing_extensions  pkgs/main/win-64::typing_extensions-3.7.4.1-py37_0

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  anaconda-project                               0.8.3-py_0 --> 0.8.4-py_0
  asn1crypto                                   1.0.1-py37_0 --> 1.3.0-py37_0
  astroid                                      2.3.1-py37_0 --> 2.3.3-py37_0
  astropy                              3.2.1-py37he774522_0 --> 4.0-py37he774522_0
  attrs                                         19.2.0-py_0 --> 19.3.0-py_0
  babel                                          2.7.0-py_0 --> 2.8.0-py_0
  backports.functoo~                               1.5-py_2 --> 1.6.1-py_0
  beautifulsoup4                               4.8.0-py37_0 --> 4.8.2-py37_0
  bitarray                             1.0.1-py37he774522_0 --> 1.2.1-py37he774522_0
  bokeh                                        1.3.4-py37_0 --> 2.0.0-py37_0
  bottleneck                           1.2.1-py37h452e1ab_1 --> 1.3.2-py37h2a96729_0
  ca-certificates     anaconda::ca-certificates-2019.8.28-0 --> pkgs/main::ca-certificates-2020.1.1-0
  certifi                anaconda::certifi-2019.9.11-py37_0 --> pkgs/main::certifi-2019.11.28-py37_0
  cffi                                1.12.3-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 1.14.0-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  cloudpickle                                    1.2.2-py_0 --> 1.3.0-py_0
  colorama           pkgs/main/win-64::colorama-0.4.1-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::colorama-0.4.3-py_0
  contextlib2                                    0.6.0-py_0 --> 0.6.0.post1-py_0
  cryptography                           2.7-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 2.8-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  curl                                    7.65.3-h2a8f88b_0 --> 7.68.0-h2a8f88b_0
  cython                             0.29.13-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.29.15-py37ha925a31_0
  cytoolz                             0.10.0-py37he774522_0 --> 0.10.1-py37he774522_0
  dask                                           2.5.2-py_0 --> 2.12.0-py_0
  dask-core                                      2.5.2-py_0 --> 2.12.0-py_0
  decorator          pkgs/main/win-64::decorator-4.4.0-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::decorator-4.4.2-py_0
  distributed        pkgs/main/noarch::distributed-2.5.2-p~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::distributed-2.12.0-py37_0
  docutils                                    0.15.2-py37_0 --> 0.16-py37_0
  fsspec                                         0.5.2-py_0 --> 0.6.2-py_0
  future                                      0.17.1-py37_0 --> 0.18.2-py37_0
  h5py                                 2.9.0-py37h5e291fa_0 --> 2.10.0-py37h5e291fa_0
  imageio                                      2.6.0-py37_0 --> 2.6.1-py37_0
  imagesize          pkgs/main/win-64::imagesize-1.1.0-py3~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::imagesize-1.2.0-py_0
  importlib_metadata                            0.23-py37_0 --> 1.5.0-py37_0
  intel-openmp                                   2019.4-245 --> 2020.0-166
  ipykernel                            5.1.2-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 5.1.4-py37h39e3cac_0
  ipython                              7.8.0-py37h39e3cac_0 --> 7.13.0-py37h5ca1d4c_0
  jedi                                        0.15.1-py37_0 --> 0.16.0-py37_0
  jinja2                                        2.10.3-py_0 --> 2.11.1-py_0
  joblib             pkgs/main/win-64::joblib-0.13.2-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::joblib-0.14.1-py_0
  jsonschema                                   3.0.2-py37_0 --> 3.2.0-py37_0
  jupyter_client                               5.3.3-py37_1 --> 5.3.4-py37_0
  jupyter_console    pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_console-6.0~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::jupyter_console-6.1.0-py_0
  jupyter_core       pkgs/main/noarch::jupyter_core-4.5.0-~ --> pkgs/main/win-64::jupyter_core-4.6.1-py37_0
  jupyterlab                             1.1.4-pyhf63ae98_0 --> 1.2.6-pyhf63ae98_0
  keyring                                     18.0.0-py37_0 --> 21.1.0-py37_0
  krb5                                    1.16.1-hc04afaa_7 --> 1.17.1-hc04afaa_0
  lazy-object-proxy                    1.4.2-py37he774522_0 --> 1.4.3-py37he774522_0
  libcurl                                 7.65.3-h2a8f88b_0 --> 7.68.0-h2a8f88b_0
  liblief                                  0.9.0-ha925a31_2 --> 0.9.0-ha925a31_3
  libpython               conda-forge::libpython-2.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main::libpython-2.1-py37_0
  libssh2                                  1.8.2-h7a1dbc1_0 --> 1.9.0-h7a1dbc1_1
  libtiff                                 4.0.10-hb898794_2 --> 4.1.0-h56a325e_0
  llvmlite                            0.29.0-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.31.0-py37ha925a31_0
  lxml                                 4.4.1-py37h1350720_0 --> 4.5.0-py37h1350720_0
  matplotlib                           3.1.1-py37hc8f65d3_0 --> 3.1.3-py37_0
  mkl                                            2019.4-245 --> 2020.0-166
  mkl_fft                             1.0.14-py37h14836fe_0 --> 1.0.15-py37h14836fe_0
  mock                  pkgs/main/win-64::mock-3.0.5-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::mock-4.0.1-py_0
  more-itertools     pkgs/main/win-64::more-itertools-7.2.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::more-itertools-8.2.0-py_0
  nbconvert                                    5.6.0-py37_1 --> 5.6.1-py37_0
  nbformat           pkgs/main/win-64::nbformat-4.4.0-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::nbformat-5.0.4-py_0
  networkx                                         2.3-py_0 --> 2.4-py_0
  notebook                                     6.0.1-py37_0 --> 6.0.3-py37_0
  numba                               0.45.1-py37hf9181ef_0 --> 0.48.0-py37h47e9c7a_0
  numexpr                              2.7.0-py37hdce8814_0 --> 2.7.1-py37h25d0782_0
  numpy                               1.16.5-py37h19fb1c0_0 --> 1.18.1-py37h93ca92e_0
  numpy-base                          1.16.5-py37hc3f5095_0 --> 1.18.1-py37hc3f5095_1
  numpydoc                                       0.9.1-py_0 --> 0.9.2-py_0
  openpyxl                                       3.0.0-py_0 --> 3.0.3-py_0
  openssl               anaconda::openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_2 --> pkgs/main::openssl-1.1.1d-he774522_4
  packaging                                       19.2-py_0 --> 20.3-py_0
  pandas                              0.25.1-py37ha925a31_0 --> 1.0.1-py37h47e9c7a_0
  parso                                          0.5.1-py_0 --> 0.6.1-py_0
  partd                                          1.0.0-py_0 --> 1.1.0-py_0
  path.py                                       12.0.1-py_0 --> 12.4.0-0
  pillow                               6.2.0-py37hdc69c19_0 --> 7.0.0-py37hcc1f983_0
  pluggy                                      0.13.0-py37_0 --> 0.13.1-py37_0
  prompt_toolkit                                2.0.10-py_0 --> 3.0.3-py_0
  psutil                               5.6.3-py37he774522_0 --> 5.7.0-py37he774522_0
  py                      pkgs/main/win-64::py-1.8.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::py-1.8.1-py_0
  py-lief                              0.9.0-py37ha925a31_2 --> 0.9.0-py37ha925a31_3
  pycurl                            7.43.0.3-py37h7a1dbc1_0 --> 7.43.0.5-py37h7a1dbc1_0
  pygments                                       2.4.2-py_0 --> 2.5.2-py_0
  pylint                                       2.4.2-py37_0 --> 2.4.4-py37_0
  pyodbc                              4.0.27-py37ha925a31_0 --> 4.0.30-py37ha925a31_0
  pyopenssl                                   19.0.0-py37_0 --> 19.1.0-py37_0
  pyparsing                                      2.4.2-py_0 --> 2.4.6-py_0
  pyrsistent                          0.15.4-py37he774522_0 --> 0.15.7-py37he774522_0
  pytables                             3.5.2-py37h1da0976_1 --> 3.6.1-py37h1da0976_0
  pytest                                       5.2.1-py37_0 --> 5.3.5-py37_0
  pytest-astropy     pkgs/main/win-64::pytest-astropy-0.5.~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::pytest-astropy-0.8.0-py_0
  pytest-doctestplus                             0.4.0-py_0 --> 0.5.0-py_0
  python-dateutil    pkgs/main/win-64::python-dateutil-2.8~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::python-dateutil-2.8.1-py_0
  pywavelets                           1.0.3-py37h8c2d366_1 --> 1.1.1-py37he774522_0
  pywin32                                223-py37hfa6e2cd_1 --> 227-py37he774522_1
  pywinpty                                  0.5.5-py37_1000 --> 0.5.7-py37_0
  pyyaml                               5.1.2-py37he774522_0 --> 5.3-py37he774522_0
  pyzmq                               18.1.0-py37ha925a31_0 --> 18.1.1-py37ha925a31_0
  qtawesome                                      0.6.0-py_0 --> 0.6.1-py_0
  qtconsole                                      4.5.5-py_0 --> 4.7.1-py_0
  requests                                    2.22.0-py37_0 --> 2.23.0-py37_0
  rope                                          0.14.0-py_0 --> 0.16.0-py_0
  ruamel_yaml                        0.15.46-py37hfa6e2cd_0 --> 0.15.87-py37he774522_0
  scikit-image                        0.15.0-py37ha925a31_0 --> 0.16.2-py37h47e9c7a_0
  scikit-learn                        0.21.3-py37h6288b17_0 --> 0.22.1-py37h6288b17_0
  scipy                                1.3.1-py37h29ff71c_0 --> 1.4.1-py37h9439919_0
  seaborn            pkgs/main/win-64::seaborn-0.9.0-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::seaborn-0.10.0-py_0
  setuptools                                  41.4.0-py37_0 --> 46.0.0-py37_0
  six                                         1.12.0-py37_0 --> 1.14.0-py37_0
  soupsieve                                    1.9.3-py37_0 --> 1.9.5-py37_0
  sphinx                                         2.2.0-py_0 --> 2.4.0-py_0
  sphinxcontrib-web~                             1.1.2-py_0 --> 1.2.0-py_0
  sqlalchemy                           1.3.9-py37he774522_0 --> 1.3.13-py37he774522_0
  sqlite                                  3.30.0-he774522_0 --> 3.31.1-he774522_0
  statsmodels                         0.10.1-py37h8c2d366_0 --> 0.11.0-py37he774522_0
  sympy                                          1.4-py37_0 --> 1.5.1-py37_0
  tbb                                     2019.4-h74a9793_0 --> 2020.0-h74a9793_0
  tblib                                          1.4.0-py_0 --> 1.6.0-py_0
  terminado                                    0.8.2-py37_0 --> 0.8.3-py37_0
  testpath           pkgs/main/win-64::testpath-0.4.2-py37~ --> pkgs/main/noarch::testpath-0.4.4-py_0
  tornado                              6.0.3-py37he774522_0 --> 6.0.4-py37he774522_1
  tqdm                                          4.36.1-py_0 --> 4.42.1-py_0
  urllib3                                     1.24.2-py37_0 --> 1.25.8-py37_0
  vs2015_runtime                     14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_0 --> 14.16.27012-hf0eaf9b_1
  wcwidth            pkgs/main/win-64::wcwidth-0.1.7-py37_0 --> pkgs/main/noarch::wcwidth-0.1.8-py_0
  werkzeug                                      0.16.0-py_0 --> 1.0.0-py_0
  wheel                                       0.33.6-py37_0 --> 0.34.2-py37_0
  xlsxwriter                                     1.2.1-py_0 --> 1.2.7-py_0
  xlwings                                    0.15.10-py37_0 --> 0.17.1-py37_0
  zipp                                           0.6.0-py_0 --> 2.2.0-py_0

The following packages will be SUPERSEDED by a higher-priority channel:

  conda                                         conda-forge --> pkgs/main
  ffmpeg                 conda-forge::ffmpeg-4.2-h6538335_0 --> pkgs/main::ffmpeg-4.2-ha925a31_0
  python-levenshtein conda-forge::python-levenshtein-0.12.~ --> pkgs/main::python-levenshtein-0.12.0-py37he774522_1001

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  anaconda                                   2019.10-py37_0 --> custom-py37_1
  pycosat                              0.6.3-py37hfa6e2cd_0 --> 0.6.3-py37he774522_0
```

Can someone help me?

Comment: My personal opinion, I wouldn't bother changing until the distribution includes python 3.8.

Comment: Is there something specific that you're trying to achieve? Probably the easiest way to get everything up-to-date is to run `conda update --all` - you can find a discussion about the merits and differences of that vs `conda update anaconda` [here](https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1414)

Comment: I am trying to update the entire anaconda. The manual way would be to uninstall that version and install the new one. But I would lose all the packages already installed

Comment: But *why* are you trying to update the entire Anaconda? Is there something specific that you're trying to achieve other than feeling good that it's up-to-date?

Comment: Whenever it releases a new version, I go there and install it just to keep everything up to date

Comment: @DaniloPerl Keep what up to date? You can always update the packages in your environment regardless, no? By the way, which channels are you using?